# Duplicate Derived Object via C++ Template

Tags: c++, templates

I know this doesn't compile, and I understand that the "DerivedTemplate" type doesn't directly implement the abstract member function. What I would like to know is why, i.e. what rule prevents this from working?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename DuplicateType, typename DuplicatedReturnType = DuplicateType>
struct EnableDuplication
{
    virtual ~EnableDuplication()
    {}
    virtual std::unique_ptr<DuplicatedReturnType> duplicate() const
    {
        std::cout << "Using the templated duplication." << std::endl;
        const auto& thisObj{static_cast<const DuplicateType&>(*this)};
        return std::make_unique<DuplicateType>(thisObj);
    }
};

struct Base
{
    Base(int value) : value_(value)
    {}
    virtual ~Base()
    {}
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> duplicate() const =0;

    const int value_;
};

struct DerivedTemplate : Base, EnableDuplication<DerivedTemplate, Base>
{
    DerivedTemplate(int value) : Base(value)
    {}
};

struct DerivedImplement : Base
{
    DerivedImplement(int value) : Base(value)
    {}
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> duplicate() const override
    {
        std::cout << "Using the implented duplication." << std::endl;
        return std::make_unique<DerivedImplement>(*this);
    }

};

void printValue(const Base& original, const std::unique_ptr<Base>& copy)
{
    std::cout << "Value of derived is: " << original.value_ << 
        "\nValue of copy is: " << copy->value_ << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    DerivedTemplate dt{5};
    auto copyt{dt.duplicate()};
    printValue(dt, copyt);

    DerivedImplement di{5};
    auto copyi{di.duplicate()};
    printValue(di, copyi);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would help, if you mentioned what exactly is not working / what error message you get. I guess the gurus will spot it immediately, but I dont ;)

Comment: Here's the error message: error: cannot declare variable 'dt' to be of abstract type 'DerivedTemplate' duplicate() const =0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't compile because `DerivedTemplate` derives from `Base` yet does not implement a pure virtual function:

```
virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> duplicate() const =0;
```

It will work if you implement said function:

```
struct DerivedTemplate : Base, EnableDuplication<DerivedTemplate, Base>
{
    DerivedTemplate(int value) : Base(value)
    {}

    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> duplicate() const override
    {
        std::cout << "DerivedTemplate::duplicate()\n";
        return std::make_unique<DerivedTemplate>(*this);
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f67d0c1f8f97f008)

Comment: Yes, but what would be the point of EnableDuplication, it's basically DerivedImplement then. What I'm seeking to understand is why the implementation from EnableDuplication does not count as the implementation.

Comment: It's because the implementation from `EnableDuplication` does not derive from `Base` and therefore `Base` has no pointer to its method in its vtable. Basically what happens when you derive from an object and implement a virtual function, the base class will then know about that virtual function. In your situation this has not happened.

Answer (score 1):

Your hirarchy is like so:

```
EnableDuplication  Base
     \              /
     DerivedTemplate
```

DerivedTemplate inherits the same method from both base classes. You are not overriding anything. In my opinion your statement is wrong:"and I understand that the "DerivedTemplate" type doesn't directly implement the abstract member function." - The problem is it doesn't even indirectly. It just doesn't at all. What you want the language to do is to override but that you haven't told it to do so.

Comment: The code for EnableDuplication's duplicate member function has the same signature and is virtual just as the Base's abstract. Why does it not match inside the derived class? What rule makes the compiler behave this way?

Comment: I played around a little bit and it appears that even if it weren't a template you still wouldn't be able to do this inherited override. What i tried to do is `struct DerivedImplement` with `struct DerivedTemplate : DerivedImplement, Base` (and some dirty casting to get rid of noise errors) which leads to the same compile errors.

Comment: It appears to be a deliberate design choice of c++ to not auto-connect two different inheritance chains within a single class. If it would then you could get a lot of unwanted behaviour when combining the features c++ provides. Polymorphism, template programming, overload and default parameter, combine those alone and you make it pretty hard to know what's going on and when even without the functionality you asked for